# MTS Mblaze in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, usb-modem

How to let Ubuntu auto detect a MTS Mblaze USB modem without having to restart Ubuntu.

Every time I plug in, I would only have to restart my Ubuntu to make the modem work. I have also tried restarting some services such networking, network-interface & network-manager.

Please provide a solution to make detect the USB modem without having to restart the entire operating system.

Answer (score 0):

It seems some kind  file missing. Try updating your system through update center and then try it again.

In my experience with some modems (ZTE and Huawei) the availability to use the Broadband modem is based on the behaviour of the modem itself. This is because these modems were designed to be functioning on specific OS. IF you have the recommended software for your USB modem try installing it,then connecting via it.

Else try dowloading it using [this Rapidshare link](https://rapidshare.com/#!download%7C462p7%7C514013822%7CCrossPlatformUI-V2.1.2-SSTL-ALL-ubuntu.deb%7C8649%7C0%7C0) and install this after connecting the modem and then try reconnecting after restarting.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around.
Just turn on and then turn off "enable mobile broadband". Then connect.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an old post, but I had the same issue and with some trail and error i managed to connect my MTS dongle to internet, I have written a post about it [here](http://ananthasharma.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/how-to-use-mts-mblaze-with-ubuntu-linux/), hope this helps someone.MTS card wasn't connecting was because the default setting shipped with Ubuntu 12.x is not complete for MTS (not sure about other providers), so we need to adjust the configuration a bit to get the dongle working.

The main reason my MTS dongle didnt work is "it was not activated" it was a new card and i plugged it into my ubuntu 12.10, finally i had to use windows and the bundled software to activate the card. things worked fine from that point.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.